# scope of eval function in python

Tags: python, eval, python-internals

Consider the following example:

```
i=7
j=8
k=10
def test():
    i=1
    j=2
    k=3
    return dict((name,eval(name)) for name in ['i','j','k'])
```

It returns:

```
>>> test()
{'i': 7, 'k': 10, 'j': 8}
```

Why eval does not take into consideration the variables defined inside the function? From the documentation, optionally you can pass a globals and a locals dictionary. What does it means?Finally, how can I modify this small case to make it work?

Comment: you could modify it to work by adding `global` before variable declaration inside a function but that's a bad idea, on the other hand, using `eval` is usually a bad idea as well.

Comment: What rusty said - unless you're sure you _have_ to use eval, stay far away from it.

Comment: @l4mpi I knew that eval is a bad idea, but i was just playing around with scopes, and i just didn't understand this behaviour

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Generators are [implemented as function scopes](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/executionmodel.html):

> The scope of names defined in a class block is limited to the class
>   block; it does not extend to the code blocks of methods – this
>   **includes generator expressions since they are implemented using a
>   function scope**.

So, the generator inside the `dict()` constructor has its own `locals()` dictionary. Now let's take a look at [`Py_eval`'s source code](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/ce72e3c45884/Python/bltinmodule.c#l640), specially when both `globals()` and `locals()` are None:

```
if (globals == Py_None) {
        globals = PyEval_GetGlobals();
        if (locals == Py_None)
            locals = PyEval_GetLocals();
    }
```

So, for your example [`PyEval_GetLocals()`](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/reflection.html#c.PyEval_GetLocals) will be empty at the moment the loop is executing and `globals()` will be the global dictionary. Note that `i`, `j` and `k` defined inside the function are not in local scope of generator, rather they are in its enclosing scope:

```
>>> dict((name,eval(name, globals(), {})) for name in ['i', 'j', 'k'])
{'i': 7, 'k': 10, 'j': 8}
```

Answer (score 4):

This occurs because the *generator expression* has a **different scope** to the *function*:

```
>>> def test():
    i, j, k = range(1, 4)
    return dict((j, locals()) for _ in range(i))

>>> test()
{2: {'.0': <listiterator object at 0x02F50A10>, 'j': 2, '_': 0}}
```

Using `j` inside the scope binds it from the function, as that's the nearest enclosing scope, but `i` and `k` are not locally bound (as `k` isn't referenced and `i` is only used to create the `range`).

---

Note that you can avoid this issue with:

```
return dict(i=i, j=j, k=k)
```

or a dictionary literal:

```
return {'i': i, 'j': j, 'k': k}
```