# Why can't I refer to one class member in the definition of another in some cases?

Tags: python

I'm trying to reference one class member in the definition of another, which seems to work inside a list comprehension, but not a dict or "tuple" comprehension:

```
class Bork(object):
    DATA = (1, 2, 3)
    LIST = [tuple(x * x for x in DATA) for z in (4, 5, 6)]
    TUPLE = tuple(tuple(x * x for x in DATA) for z in (4, 5, 6))            # NameError: global name 'DATA' is not defined
    DICT = {z: tuple(x * x for x in DATA) for z in (4, 5, 6)}               # NameError: global name 'DATA' is not defined
    DICT2 = dict((z, tuple(x * x for x in DATA)) for z in (4, 5, 6))        # NameError: global name 'DATA' is not defined

Bork()
```

Am I doing something dumb, or does this seem inconsistent?  This is Python 2.7 if that makes a difference.

Comment: Because generators have their own scope and list comprehension don't(only in Python 2).

Comment: See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/27378660/3001761

Comment: See the first code snippet here: https://docs.python.org/2/reference/executionmodel.html