# Eval scope in a function

Tags: python-2.7, eval

I have the following scripts creating a dictionary from a list of strings:

```
def dummy(a, b):
    c = a+1
    lst =["a","b","c"]
    return dict((k, eval(k)) for k in lst)

if __name__ == "__main__":
     dummy(0.01, "2015-01-29")
```

When I run it in terminal, I have the follwoing error:

```
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

It seems that the variable `a` is not found in the scope of function `dummy` when `eval` acts...but I do not see why ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it a list first:

```
def dummy(a, b):
    c = a + 1
    lst =["a","b","c"]
    return dict([(k, eval(k)) for k in lst])

if __name__ == "__main__":
     print(dummy(0.01, "2015-01-29"))
```

The version you have is a generator. See this for more details:

- [scope of eval function in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27378660/scope-of-eval-function-in-python)

To quote the relevant part:

> The scope of names defined in a class block is limited to the class
>   block; it does not extend to the code blocks of methods – this
>   **includes generator expressions since they are implemented using a
>   function scope**.

Comment: Ow! This makes sense! Indeed I am using a generator...sorry just coming back in Python after 6 months makes me realize how I lost !